# cannot read property of state of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am getting Cannot read property 'state' of undefined on button click. Here is my work

```
constructor(props){
  super()

  this.state = {
    email:"",
    guestName:"",
    staffName:"",

  };
   this.onSend = this.onSend.bind()
}


  onSend(){
      let val = this.state
      console.log(val)
  }
render(){
return(
<Button variant="contained" color="primary" className={"send"} onClick={this.onSend}>
        Send
      </Button>)
   }
```

What am I missing?

Comment: The quick fix: just add `this` in the parentheses `this.onSend = this.onSend.bind(this)`.

Comment: @toy moy. i just outlined three different ways for you to approach this. Pick one that works best for you. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is that `this` in your `onSend()` function does not refer to the class, but to the element that called the function (in your case the `Button` element).

To fix this you can change the function to an arrow function like in the code below or you can bind the `this` reference (the class) with `.bind(this)` (so `onClick={this.onSend.bind(this)}`)

```
constructor(props){
  super()

  this.state = {
    email:"",
    guestName:"",
    staffName:"",   
  };
}

onSend = () => {
    let val = this.state
    console.log(val)
}

render(){
  return(
    <Button variant="contained" color="primary" className={"send"} onClick={this.onSend}>
        Send
    </Button>)
 }
```

Comment: Should be onSend = () => ... Not... onSend => () => ... You also don't need the binding in the constructor if you have onSend as an arrow function

Comment: You still don't need to bind in the constructor. One or the other.

Answer (score 1):

When you define an event-handler as a non-arrow function like onSend() in a class, the this keyword is not bound to your component's context. Try any of the following:

1) Bind this, which looks like you almost completed:

```
constructor(props){
  super()

  this.state = {
    email:"",
    guestName:"",
    staffName:"",

  };
   this.onSend = this.onSend.bind(this)
}
```

2) Convert onSend() to be an arrow function. Thanks to lexical scoping, the this keyword will now point towards the owner of onSend which is the class-component itself.

```
onSend = () => {
   let val = this.state
   console.log(val)
}
```

3) Bind the this keyword inside your event-handler

```
<Button variant="contained" color="primary" className={"send"} onClick={() => this.onSend().bind(this)}>
        Send
      </Button>)
   }
```

Comment: Don't use #3… anonymous functions in render function cause unnecessary rerenders

Comment: @andymccullough. Thank you, I actually never noticed that before.

Comment: Not a big deal when it's only a button, but a habit worth avoiding for larger/deeper component props